Wannier orbital shape and bonding
In the Wannierization of CsPbBr3, xsf files have been generated. One of these files displays an orbital centered on a Pb atom. How can I interpret this orbital's shape and spatial spread? Additionally, based on its characteristics, how would this orbital contribute to the formation of a sigma or pi bond?"
The xsf image is attached (Pink: Cs, Gray: Pb, Purple: Br).

